# PowerShell define Object in Function?

Tags: function, powershell, dictionary

Do I need to redefine Objects in Functions?

I have following main.ps1

```
$MyDict = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,string]' 
loadDict([ref]$MyDict)
```

and I have a functions.psm1 with the function

```
function loadDict([ref]$return)
{
    #pseudo - load data from table
    foreach ($TableRow in $LoadTable){
        if($return.ContainsKey($TableRow.KEYID) -eq $false){
            $return.Add($TableRow.KEYID, $TableRow.TEXT.Trim())
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the following Error..

> [System.Management.Automation.PSReference'1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]] "ContainsKey" Method not found

When I do not call the Function, but use the Function Code in Main, there is no Problem.

(corrected "[" typo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is *no*. You don't need to redefine the objects.

Like Esperento57 mentioned, you have a `[` within your if condition. Anyhow, you may consider to use a bultin *hashtable*:

```
function loadDict
{
    Param
    (
        [hashtable]$MyDict
    )
    #pseudo - load data from table
    foreach ($TableRow in $LoadTable)
    {
        if($MyDict.ContainsKey($TableRow.KEYID) -eq $false)
        {
            $MyDict.Add($TableRow.KEYID, $TableRow.TEXT.Trim())
        }
    }
}

$MyDict = @{}
loadDict([ref]$MyDict)
```

Comment: Thanks, i got that "Dictionary" Thing from a friend of mine who told me it is a lot faster than bultin hashtable. i have a few Tables which are a few hundred Megabytes "thick". I will try your Solution and give Feedback.

Comment: Can you provide us an example of `$LoadTable`? You can probably speed up your script by populating the list at once.

Comment: :/ sorry no, it contains internal ERP Data. They hold for example ShopItem Descriptions and stuff..  What i do is .. load that dictionaries once a day and hold them in RAM. So that Dict Load takes about 10 Minutes from SQL Server, which is indeed hellish fast. But i need to Transform or Concatenate some Data before it is stored in that Dict.

Comment: Hashtable worked perfectly the same way, and it's not really slower than dict. I am not good with measuring time.

Answer (score 0):

remove ref into your parameter and put the type like this :

```
function loadDict([system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,string]]$return)
{
    #pseudo - load data from table
    foreach ($TableRow in $LoadTable){
        if($return.ContainsKey($TableRow.KEYID) -eq $false){
            $return.Add($TableRow.KEYID, $TableRow.TEXT.Trim())
        }
    }
}

$MyDict = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,string]' 
loadDict($MyDict)
```

Comment: With this i have Invalid Data Error,  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError

Comment: i have try this, this code work. You have an other problem now.May be into your load